# jQuery function before the Postback for FileUpload in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

So, I have an .aspx webpage as follows:

```
.. 
<form id="frm" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload  runat="server" id="fileupload" onchange="browsed()" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Upload_Click" id="uploadbutton" class="uploadbutton" Text="start upload" Enabled="false" />
    <div id="nfo" style="display: none">
         blabla
    </div>
</form>
..
```

Now, as you can guess correctly, user chooses file to upload, clicks `#uploadbutton` and, voila, `Upload_Click` is called after the postback.
Then, I want to show div `#nfo` with some jQuery effects during the upload. To do this, I write:

```
$(function() {
    $('.uploadbutton').click(function() {
        $('#nfo').slideDown().show("fast");
     })
})
```

and everything works just fine, until the user starts browsing in IE...
First of all, in IE, user has to click `#uploadbutton` twice - first time to display `#nfo`, second time, for some reason, to initiate postback. 
Secondly, after the postback, `Upload_Click`'s `this.fileupload.HasFile` shows false.
FF and Chrome works quite well though.

As far, as I can understand this - in IE jQuery's function prevents something important for `asp:FileUpload` from happening and stops the postback. Though, on the second click it does initiate the postback, but still with no info for `asp:FileUpload`'s `Upload_Click`.

Any help?

---

**Update:**
followed @joelt'd advice. turned out, there was some different problem, never thought it could be of importance, so I didn't provide source code for that part =(
see [localizing <asp:FileUpload>. IE problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489120/localizing-aspfileupload-ie-problem)

Comment: return false; after the "click" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Button1").click(function() {
                $("#progress").show();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <div id="progress" style="display:none; background-color:Red;">test</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine for me in FF and IE7, except in IE, the progress indicator doesn't really give you anything because of how it's rendering, I suppose. I would say the biggest difference between our code is the "onchange=browsed()" function. It's possible that's not getting called until you click the button? In any case, I would start with a stripped down page like this, and start adding in other elements you have until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Upload_Click" id="uploadbutton" 
   class="uploadbutton" Text="start upload" Enabled="false" 
   OnClientClick="return myFunction();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    $('#nfo').slideDown().show("fast");
    return true;//THIS WILL FIRE POSTBACK EVENT
   //return false;//THIS WILL STOP POSTBACK EVENT, WHICH YOU MAY WANT IF THERE 
                  //IS NO FILE SELECTED
}
</script>
```