# localizing <asp:FileUpload>. IE problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, file-upload

what i want to do is localize `<asp:FileUpload>` control. as far as i understand it is not possible, because `input file` is being rendered by a browser and there is no way to control it from the server.
so i do this: i create `<asp:FileUpload>`, make it transparent, create `input text` and `input button` and write

```
function browse() {
    $('#fileupload').click();
}
```

on `input button` `onclick` event.
firefox and chrome does fine, IE8 - does not: it opens `fileupload`'s "Browse..." dialog, writes it's value to `input text` (via `$('#filepath').val($('#fileupload').val());`), but when i start uploading, there is this problem: [jQuery function before the Postback for FileUpload in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469036/jquery-function-before-the-postback-for-fileupload-in-asp-net)

So my question is: is there any other (better?) way to override upload control (custom width, localized texts on button etc...), that works on every browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) so far?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Conner So I should reverse engineer the code of the flash plugin to post it here?^^ If the site of the plugin gets invalid the plugin won't be recommendable anymore at all...

Comment: This "answer" is really a question trying to glean more information from the asker. Also, this link may become broken in the future, and SO is looking to create sustainable answers to programming questions. You can provide links in answers to libraries that may assist in answering the problem, but the discussion of the question should be more thorough than one sentence. I don't mean any ill-will toward you for making this suggestion - I appreciate that you're answering at all! SO is just trying to improve its formatting and I'm trying to help.